# How to use a function expression for the Paginator sort order?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

When it comes to sorting ip addresses in Database I use the INET_ATON function provided by MySQL.

Now when I'm trying to do this in CakePHP 3 (which I'm sorta new to) I fail.

Here's what I got:

```
class Ip extends Entity
{

    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
     * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
     * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false,
    ];

    protected $_virtual = ['ip_address'];

    protected function _getIpAddress()
    {
        $vc = (new FunctionsBuilder())->inet_aton(['ip' => 'literal']);
        return $vc;
    }
}
```

Here's my Controller method.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\Database\FunctionsBuilder;
/**
 * Ips Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\IpsTable $Ips
 */
class IpsController extends AppController
{

    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Users'],
            'order' => [(new FunctionsBuilder())->inet_aton(['ip' => 'literal'])]
        ];
        $this->set('ips', $this->paginate($this->Ips));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['ips']);
    }
```

By knowing that sorting on virtual properties probably not might work, I'm not sure if I'm using the right approach to et this done.

Does anyone recommend best practices to achieve this scenario?

Comment: Do you want to sort your data ?

Comment: Jep, i want to sort ip addresses in the way that 1.1.1.18 would not appear before 1.1.1.2.

Comment: May you add your controller/index method please ? And add also what your output now and what actually do you want to see ?

Comment: Do you want to see your ip as a DESC order ? or as a ip pattern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use an additional column instead

Personally I'd instead additionally store the integer representation of the IP in a separate column and use that one for ordering. This will not only give you better performance as the DBMS can use indices, it will also avoid the additional logic necessary to handle function expressions, and let you use the Pagination component as usual.

In the view then simply use the name of the new column, and define the name to display for the sort link manually, like

```
<?= $this->Paginator->sort('ip_int', 'IP') ?>
```

## Using expressions

### Via options or a custom query

In its current state, pagination isn't able to handle function expressions, but only column names. At least this is true in combination with the pagination view helper! While you can define expressions for the `order` option, like

```
$this->paginate['order'] = [
    new \Cake\Database\Expression\OrderClauseExpression(
        $this->Ips->query()->func()->inet_aton(['ip' => 'literal']),
        'ASC'
    )
];
```

or use a custom query, like

```
$query = $this->Ips->find();
$query->orderAsc($query->func()->inet_aton(['ip' => 'literal']));

$this->set('ips', $this->paginate($query));
```

you'll have to use a little bit of custom logic to get this working along with the view, as the pagination helper is desingned to handle column names (strings) only.

#### Dynamic ordering with view helper

Now if you want to use the pagination view helper too, you'll have to create some logic that evaluates the sort column and direction generated by the helper, and configure the options/query manually similar to the above examples.

Here's a basic example, using the the `Query::orderAsc()` and `Query::orderDesc()` methods that make it possible to define the direction when using function expressions (expressions cannot be combined with further values via `Query::order()`).

```
$query = $this->Ips->find();

$sort = $this->request->query('sort');
if ($sort === null || $sort === 'ip') {
    $method = 'orderAsc';
    if ($this->request->query('direction') === 'desc') {
        $method = 'orderDesc';
    }
    $query->{$method}($query->func()->inet_aton(['ip' => 'literal']));
}

$this->set('articles', $this->paginate($query));
```

This should be mostly self-explantory, first check whether the `sort` key genereated by the Paginator helper was passed, and if it wasn't or was and it's your IP column, apply your custom order with respect to the possibly set `direction` key. If `sort` is not your IP column, simply ignore it, and the Paginator will pick up the values and evaluate and use them as usual.

Similary you could set the direction when manually creating `OrderClauseExpression` instances, however personally I'd probably stick with using a custom query and the function builder instead.

#### A little more DRY?

If you'd like to make this a little more reusable, you may want to look into a custom/extended paginator component, custom finders, and behaviors.

### Entities are data containers

Last but not least, your entity has nothing to do with all this, it's just a data container, so ditch the virtual property, they cannot be used in finds anyways.

## See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Pagination > Using Controller::paginate()](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-controller-paginate)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entities > Creating Virtual Properties](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-properties)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Custom Finder Methods](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-find-methods)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Selecting Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data)**

Comment: Very good explanation! I ditched the virtual property and chose the view helper approach! Though an extra column with integer representation might have been the easiest way.